# Vulkan + GLFW + Cmake issues with linking under linux enviroment

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, vulkan

I am trying to link vulkan to my project, and I got some weird erros.
Below is my CMakeList, I have build vulkan on my computer, also I have installed glfw.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp )
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})


find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
if (glfw3_FOUND)
    include_directories(${glfw3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${glfw3_LIBRARIES})
endif (glfw3_FOUND)

pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
message(STATUS "Found GLFW3 in ${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR}")

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} GLEW)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} )
```

And this is the errors I get every time I try to run the makefile :

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable VulkanTest
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `_glfwInitVulkan':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
vulkan.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `_glfwTerminateVulkan':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x4a8): undefined reference to `dlclose'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `glfwGetInstanceProcAddress':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x815): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `translateKeyCode':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `XGetKeyboardMapping'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `createKeyTables':
x11_init.c:(.text+0xc3d): undefined reference to `XkbGetMap'
x11_init.c:(.text+0xc60): undefined reference to `XkbGetNames'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x137d): undefined reference to `XkbFreeNames'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1393): undefined reference to `XkbFreeKeyboard'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `hasUsableInputMethodStyle':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x14ab): undefined reference to `XGetIMValues'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1505): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `getSupportedAtom':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1554): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `detectEWMH':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x15e3): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1609): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1652): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x168d): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16a6): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16cf): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16db): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o):x11_init.c:(.text+0x16ec): more undefined references to `XFree' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x196c): undefined reference to `XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x19ad): undefined reference to `XRRQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x19e7): undefined reference to `XRRQueryVersion'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1a74): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1aa7): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGammaSize'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1ade): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b0a): undefined reference to `XRRSelectInput'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b3c): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b56): undefined reference to `XineramaIsActive'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1be9): undefined reference to `XkbQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c28): undefined reference to `XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c55): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c96): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1cd3): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1d06): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1d39): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1d6c): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1d9f): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o):x11_init.c:(.text+0x1dd2): more undefined references to `XInternAtom' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwGrabErrorHandlerX11':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2363): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwReleaseErrorHandlerX11':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2385): undefined reference to `XSync'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x238f): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwInputErrorX11':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x23e8): undefined reference to `XGetErrorText'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwCreateCursorX11':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x244e): undefined reference to `XcursorImageCreate'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x257b): undefined reference to `XcursorImageLoadCursor'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x258b): undefined reference to `XcursorImageDestroy'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformInit':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x259e): undefined reference to `XInitThreads'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x25a8): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2685): undefined reference to `XrmUniqueQuark'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x26c2): undefined reference to `XSupportsLocale'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x26d6): undefined reference to `XSetLocaleModifiers'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x26fb): undefined reference to `XOpenIM'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x273e): undefined reference to `XCloseIM'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformTerminate':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x27a9): undefined reference to `dlclose'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x27f5): undefined reference to `XFreeCursor'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2846): undefined reference to `XCloseIM'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2886): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwSetVideoModeX11':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x349): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x378): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4a6): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcConfig'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4b6): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4ce): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwRestoreVideoModeX11':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x57e): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x5aa): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x61a): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcConfig'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x62a): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x636): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitors':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x6c9): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x6f4): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputPrimary'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x740): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryScreens'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x785): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x7e7): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x97f): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xa20): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xa40): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xa53): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xbe2): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResourcesCurrent'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xc0e): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xc46): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xc52): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetVideoModes':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xccf): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResourcesCurrent'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xcfb): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xd27): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xe6b): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xe77): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xe83): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetVideoMode':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xf40): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResourcesCurrent'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xf6c): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xfc4): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xfd0): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x111f): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGammaSize'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x1149): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGamma'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x11d5): undefined reference to `XRRFreeGamma'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x1219): undefined reference to `XF86VidModeGetGammaRampSize'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x127c): undefined reference to `XF86VidModeGetGammaRamp'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x12db): undefined reference to `XRRAllocGamma'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x137e): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcGamma'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x138a): undefined reference to `XRRFreeGamma'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x13ee): undefined reference to `XF86VidModeSetGammaRamp'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `waitForVisibilityNotify':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to `XCheckTypedWindowEvent'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `getWindowState':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x44b): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `findWindowByHandle':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x643): undefined reference to `XFindContext'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `sendEventToWM':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x771): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `updateNormalHints':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x79f): undefined reference to `XAllocSizeHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x94e): undefined reference to `XSetWMNormalHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `updateWindowMode':
x11_window.c:(.text+0xae2): undefined reference to `XChangeWindowAttributes'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xb45): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xba7): undefined reference to `XDeleteProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xc52): undefined reference to `XChangeWindowAttributes'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xc98): undefined reference to `XDeleteProperty'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `updateCursorImage':
x11_window.c:(.text+0xf55): undefined reference to `XDefineCursor'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xf7b): undefined reference to `XUndefineCursor'
x11_window.c:(.text+0xfaf): undefined reference to `XDefineCursor'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `createNativeWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1017): undefined reference to `XCreateColormap'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x10c4): undefined reference to `XCreateWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1144): undefined reference to `XSaveContext'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x11bb): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x130d): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1362): undefined reference to `XSetWMProtocols'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x13ba): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1446): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x144f): undefined reference to `XAllocWMHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x14ca): undefined reference to `XSetWMHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x14d9): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1514): undefined reference to `XAllocClassHint'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1574): undefined reference to `XSetClassHint'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1583): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x15ee): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1679): undefined reference to `XCreateIC'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `writeTargetToProperty':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1829): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1964): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x19eb): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x19fb): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1a73): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1b1a): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `handleSelectionRequest':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1c84): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `pushSelectionToManager':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1d0a): undefined reference to `XConvertSelection'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1d89): undefined reference to `XCheckIfEvent'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `acquireMonitor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1e31): undefined reference to `XGetScreenSaver'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1e5c): undefined reference to `XSetScreenSaver'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1f20): undefined reference to `XMoveResizeWindow'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `releaseMonitor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2012): undefined reference to `XSetScreenSaver'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `processEvent':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2155): undefined reference to `XFilterEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2198): undefined reference to `XRRUpdateConfiguration'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2346): undefined reference to `Xutf8LookupString'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x23b0): undefined reference to `Xutf8LookupString'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x248d): undefined reference to `XLookupString'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x255c): undefined reference to `XEventsQueued'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2580): undefined reference to `XPeekEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2de2): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2e9a): undefined reference to `XConvertSelection'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x301f): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3035): undefined reference to `XFlush'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3133): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x31fb): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3211): undefined reference to `XFlush'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x328a): undefined reference to `XSetICFocus'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3317): undefined reference to `XUnsetICFocus'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwGetWindowPropertyX11':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x350d): undefined reference to `XGetWindowProperty'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformCreateWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x373f): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformDestroyWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x37c8): undefined reference to `XDestroyIC'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3836): undefined reference to `XGetSelectionOwner'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3886): undefined reference to `XDeleteContext'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x38aa): undefined reference to `XUnmapWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x38ce): undefined reference to `XDestroyWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3911): undefined reference to `XFreeColormap'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3936): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3988): undefined reference to `Xutf8SetWMProperties'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x39e7): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3a46): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3a60): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3cb9): undefined reference to `XChangeProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3cfd): undefined reference to `XDeleteProperty'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3d13): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetWindowPos':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3d84): undefined reference to `XTranslateCoordinates'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowPos':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3df9): undefined reference to `XAllocSizeHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3e26): undefined reference to `XGetWMNormalHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3e80): undefined reference to `XSetWMNormalHints'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3e8c): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3eb3): undefined reference to `XMoveWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3ec9): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetWindowSize':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x3f3d): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowSize':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x400b): undefined reference to `XResizeWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4021): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x408d): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4106): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetWindowFrameSize':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x42a9): undefined reference to `XCheckIfEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x438d): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformIconifyWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x440c): undefined reference to `XIconifyWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4422): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformRestoreWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x448d): undefined reference to `XMapWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4558): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformMaximizeWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4614): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformShowWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4657): undefined reference to `XMapWindow'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformHideWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4698): undefined reference to `XUnmapWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x46ae): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformFocusWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4730): undefined reference to `XRaiseWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x475b): undefined reference to `XSetInputFocus'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4771): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x47fe): undefined reference to `XMoveResizeWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4880): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x48d2): undefined reference to `XMoveResizeWindow'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x48e8): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformWindowFocused':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4929): undefined reference to `XGetInputFocus'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformWindowVisible':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x49c9): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformWindowMaximized':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4ab6): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformPollEvents':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4b04): undefined reference to `XPending'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4b2c): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4b8d): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformWaitEvents':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4bca): undefined reference to `XPending'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4c0b): undefined reference to `XPending'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4cd8): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4cee): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetCursorPos':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4d6c): undefined reference to `XQueryPointer'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetCursorPos':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4e40): undefined reference to `XWarpPointer'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4e5a): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetCursorMode':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4f17): undefined reference to `XGrabPointer'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4f5e): undefined reference to `XUngrabPointer'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x4fb6): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetKeyName':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5067): undefined reference to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x50b5): undefined reference to `XkbTranslateKeySym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5178): undefined reference to `XCreateFontCursor'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformDestroyCursor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x51ee): undefined reference to `XFreeCursor'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetCursor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5231): undefined reference to `XFlush'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetClipboardString':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x52ab): undefined reference to `XSetSelectionOwner'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x52d2): undefined reference to `XGetSelectionOwner'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetClipboardString':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5386): undefined reference to `XGetSelectionOwner'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5436): undefined reference to `XConvertSelection'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x5464): undefined reference to `XCheckTypedEvent'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x54d0): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x54f7): undefined reference to `XDeleteProperty'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x56ab): undefined reference to `XVisualIDFromVisual'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(posix_tls.c.o): In function `_glfwInitThreadLocalStoragePOSIX':
posix_tls.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(posix_tls.c.o): In function `_glfwTerminateThreadLocalStoragePOSIX':
posix_tls.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(posix_tls.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetCurrentContext':
posix_tls.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(posix_tls.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetCurrentContext':
posix_tls.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `chooseGLXFBConfig':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `getProcAddressGLX':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x6fe): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `_glfwInitGLX':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x81d): undefined reference to `dlopen'
glx_context.c:(.text+0x8a7): undefined reference to `dlsym'
glx_context.c:(.text+0x8d5): undefined reference to `dlsym'
glx_context.c:(.text+0x903): undefined reference to `dlsym'
glx_context.c:(.text+0x931): undefined reference to `dlsym'
glx_context.c:(.text+0x95f): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o):glx_context.c:(.text+0x98d): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `_glfwTerminateGLX':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x1012): undefined reference to `dlclose'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `_glfwChooseVisualGLX':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x1a12): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `getProcAddressEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0x6a1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `destroyContextEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0x70b): undefined reference to `dlclose'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `_glfwInitEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `dlopen'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x8dd): undefined reference to `dlsym'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x90b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x939): undefined reference to `dlsym'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x967): undefined reference to `dlsym'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x995): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o):egl_context.c:(.text+0x9c3): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `_glfwTerminateEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0xef9): undefined reference to `dlclose'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `_glfwCreateContextEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0x18d7): undefined reference to `dlopen'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(egl_context.c.o): In function `_glfwChooseVisualEGL':
egl_context.c:(.text+0x1aec): undefined reference to `XGetVisualInfo'
egl_context.c:(.text+0x1b41): undefined reference to `XFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'VulkanTest' failed
make[2]: *** [VulkanTest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any thoughts on this one? I have tried everything that I could find on the internet, but I cannot get any reference to those errors.

Comment: `dlsym` is defined in `dl` library, `XFree` is defined in `xlib` and so on.

Comment: Why do you use both `find_package` and `pkg_search_module`? Why do you link GLFW twice? Why do you link GLEW for a Vulkan app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved!

I used FINDglew.cmake from this link below :
https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv/blob/master/cmake/FindGLFW.cmake

And I Add this to my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
if (GLFW_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Glfw found")
  include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_libraries (${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
endif (GLFW_FOUND)
```

Everything works fine now, the project compiles without any errors!

Answer (score 1):

Your cmake code doesn't seem to show how you're initializing `Vulkan_LIBRARY`.  Also, you're using `VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Vulkan_LIBRARY`, which makes me suspicious of how you're initializing them.

I would expect to see something more like...

```
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I would also assume that the CMake Vulkan package finder is smart enough to include required libraries like dl and xlib in the `Vulkan_LIBRARIES` list.